# How to see the 'failure source' for static_assert in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, static-assert

In Visual Studio when trying to compile I get a static_assert, but when I click on that error it takes to to the assert itself and not the offending line.

How to find out which line triggered the static_assert?

Comment: Expecting a call stack for errors reported at compile-time is not sensible.  It is in fact that assert that produced the error.  You'll need to show a repro to get help.

Comment: @HansPassant But what's the point of an assert that doesn't show where the error is? And if that's the case is there a way to disable static_asserts? Because at least runtime error will give a callstack

Comment: @Maxim: `static_assert` usually means it can't generate code, so there is nothing to run.  Also, most failing `asserts` result in undefined behavior, which also gives no callstack.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes but where is the offending line(s) of code? Usually if the compiler fails to compile it tells you why and points to the line that breaks the compilation, the static_assert doesn't appear to so how does one use it?

Comment: @MooingDuck For debug build you can break on assert and get the callstack

Comment: Bit of a nuisance, but the same thing as a bug in a header file that forces you to divide and conquer your way to finding what's wrong in which header. If I don't know which invocation of the function triggered the assert, I'd approach this the same way: cut the code in half and see which side the assert's on. Rinse repeat

Comment: @user4581301 OK, I was kind of thinking along the same lines, I was just wondering if I was missing something, but if not that's a viable approach too, thanks

Comment: The best advice is do what you can to not get into this situation by writing small chunks of code between compiling and testing. If an error just popped up after writing a new function, the error is almost certainly in that function. Didn't work in the old days where you had limited computer time and the program pretty much had to work before you sat down at the terminal to type it in, and doesn't help much when porting software to a new platform, but when writing a new program, it helps keep you sane.

Comment: @user4581301 I found the line where it was happening in this specific case, but the reason why the thing happened in the first place is that there was a bunch of code that was working fine on Linux and Mac, but on Windows the compiler doesn't like certain datatypes passed to some templates, which is fine but that's why there was already quite a bit of code written before I tried compiling it on Windows.

Comment: Porting software is its own art. I don't know what you are working on, but sometimes it's worth having an abstraction layer to hide the system specifics from the application logic. Wouldn't have helped you here, though.

Comment: @user4581301 Who wants to be sane?  You can't be if you ever want to deal with templates in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know what you mean, because I too use Visual Studio, but I don't think you're clicking on the right thing.

For example, if you compile this in the IDE:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> void f1 () { static_assert (std::is_same <T, int>::value, "oh no it isn't"); }
template <class T> void f2 () { f1 <T> (); }

int main ()
{
    f2 <long> ();
}
```

Then you see this in the 'Error List' window:

> Error C2338 ... oh no it isn't ... test.cpp(3)

Which isn't very helpful.

However, the information you seek *is* in the Output window (under 'build'), and if we look in there, we see:

```
test.cpp
g:\source\tests\test.cpp(3): error C2338: oh no it isn't
g:\source\tests\test.cpp(4): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void f1<T>(void)' being compiled
    with
    [
        T=long
    ]
g:\source\tests\test.cpp: note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void f2<long>(void)' being compiled
```

And there is the 'stack trace' you seek (and you can double-click on things to be taken to the corresponding source line).

Simple as that.  Run it at [rextester](http://rextester.com/SZI23152) (the only online compiler I know of supporting MSVC).  Typical SO downvotes when people don't understand the question.

Comment: You know, sometimes I forget that a lot of people don't know the Output tab exists. I just assumed the asker had already looked and found it wanting. Silly me. After all, we all know what they say about "assume". Or is that me making another assumption? Gah! Assumptions about assumptions. Exiting before infinite recursion.

Comment: Well, nice when users post a vague question, almost any answer can fit the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant You think that I posted 'almost any answer'?  Seriously?

Comment: @user4581301 My output tab was missing for some reason, I actually did look for it, but when I didn't see it, I thought maybe they changed it in this version of VS, but now that I explicitly from the menu I see it works quite well for the purpose

Comment: @Maxim Yes, it's all too easy to 'undock' those guys by mistake. _Now_ you can get some real work done :)